# Failing to deploy Flask application to Heroku (Heroku tries to install SQlite even though I don't use it at all)

Tags: python, sqlite, heroku

I'm trying to create a new application at Heroku but for some reason the deploy doesn't work.

I don't know why, but it seems like Heroku tries to install SQLite3 and fails. The problem is that I don't use it at all.
Here's the build log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.7.5
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here's my runtime.txt file:

```
python-3.7.5
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
gunicorn==19.9.0
haversine==2.1.2
redis==3.0.1
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

server.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import (Flask, abort, request,
                   )
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from sessions import RedisSessionInterface
from firebase import Firebase
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from haversine import haversine as distance
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.session_interface = RedisSessionInterface()
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=60)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
fb = Firebase()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I tried to solve this over and over again and failed. I tried every solution I found and nothing seems to work. (pretty much all  the answers to this problem at Stack Overflow are "I was at wrong branch" and things like that)
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Heroku's Python buildpack.  They released a fix for it [here](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1802).

Basically it says you can either switch the branch of buildpack you're using, or manually specify a version of the stack that doesn't contain this bug.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me

Comment: No problem.  If this was the solution to your issue, please mark this as the answer.